# Mendeley Desktop is already running but may not be responding on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04, mendeley

I installed Mendeley v1.19.8 on Ubuntu 22.04 via the installer [here](https://github.com/phamquiluan/dotfiles/releases), but sometimes when I try to open it, there is an error that said:

***Mendeley Desktop is already running but may not be responding. Click the Mendeley icon in the taskbar or dock to activate it.***

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

My solutions:

1. Find and kill all Mendeley processes

```
pkill -f mende
```

2. Start it again

```
./bin/mendeleydesktop
```